# how do I compute this infinite sum in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to compute the following infinite sum in Matlab, for a given x and tau:

[image: infsum]

I tried the following code, given x=0.5 and tau=1:

```
symsum((8/pi/pi)*sin(n*pi*0.5)*sin(n*pi*0.5)*exp(-n*n*pi*pi)/n/n,1,inf)
```

But I get this:

```
(228155022448185*sum((exp(-pi^2*n^2)*((exp(-(pi*n*i)/2)*i)/2 - (exp((pi*n*i)/2)*i)/2)^2)/n^2, n == 1..Inf))/281474976710656
```

I want an explicit value, assuming the sum converges. What am I doing wrong? It seems like Matlab doesn't compute exp() when returning symsum results. How do I tell Matlab to compute evaluate the exponentials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert to double

```
double(symsum(...))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to show you a different way, one that does not require the symbolic toolbox,

```
summ  = 0;
summP = inf;
n = 1;
while abs(summP-summ) > 1e-16
    summP = summ;    
    summ = summ + sin(n*pi*0.5)*sin(n*pi*0.5)*exp(-n*n*pi*pi)/n/n;
    n = n + 1;
end

8/pi/pi * summ
```

which converges after just 1 iteration (pretty obvious, since `exp(-4*6.28..)/n/n` is so tiny, and `sin(..)` is always somewhere in `[-1 1]`). So given `tau==1` and `x==0.5`, the infinite sum is essentially the value for `n==1`.

Answer (score 0):

You should first define your variable "n" using syms. Then, you can include this variable in your symsum code.

Here's what I did:

```
syms n; AA = symsum((8/pi/pi)*sin(n*pi*0.5)*sin(n*pi*0.5)*exp(-n*n*pi*pi)/n/n,n,1,inf); BB = double(AA)
BB = 4.1925e-05
```