# Very slow infinite series with symsum in Matlab

Tags: matlab, infinite, symbolic-math, symbolic-computation

I have the following infinite series which I need to evaluate. Currently, depending on the input parameters (kappa, sigmav, thetav) this functions takes very long to compute. Is there any possibility to speed it up? The time consuming expression is symsum(..., 0, Inf)

```
 j = sym('j', 'positive');
 c =  1/((1/2*kappav)*(sigmav^2)*(1-exp(-kappav*deltat)));
 lambda = 2*c*Vt*exp(-kappav*deltat);
 v = 4*thetav/sigmav^2;
 ez = 2*c*exp(Vtt);
 % 
 p = ((exp(-1/2*(ez+lambda))*ez^(1/2*v)) / ( 2^(0.5*v)))* ... 
   vpa( symsum(   ((1/4*ez*lambda)^j)/ (gamma(1/2*v+j)*factorial(j)) ,j, 0, Inf  ));
```

PS. this is the pdf for the [non-central chi-square distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution), with some minor modifications, hence I cannot use `ncx2pdf`. I've already attempted https://stackoverflow.com/a/15966126/321749 which just results in infinity.

Comment: It results in infinity for what inputs? And for `symsum`, what happens if you sum to a large number instead? If speed is your goal, symbolic math is almost certainly not the way to go. Modifying the linked numeric approach or using power series approximations may well be faster.

Comment: the mentioned method in the link results in infinity if I sum up to 10. Do you have any hints regarding the  power series approximations?

Comment: "results in infinity if I sum up to 10" is still not helpful. For what input values? Provide an actual runnable example for your above code and for the linked code. Also, what parts of your equation blow up? Have you confirmed that it's specifically the `symsum` part and not `((exp(-1/2*(ez+lambda))*ez^(1/2*v)) / ( 2^(0.5*v)))` or the multiplication of that and the `symsum` component. Have you looked at the method that `ncx2pdf` uses? Type `edit ncx2pdf` in your command window. If your not experienced with Matlab, the code might be difficult. There are also some references in the code.